# Tableview not drilling down

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview, tabs

Ok, Here is the code in my AppDelegate that loads the Schedule nib.

```
Schedule *newestVideoController = [[Schedule alloc] initWithNibName:@"Schedule" bundle:nil];
    newestVideoController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Schedule" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"app-icon_2_newest.png"] tag:2];
    NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController, newestVideoController, nil];
    mainController.viewControllers = controllers;
```

Now here is my header file for schedule.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AnotherViewController.h"


@interface Schedule : UITableViewController
<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>    {
    NSArray *mySchedule;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *mySchedule;

@end
```

Lastly here again is my implementaion file for "Schedule".

```
#import "Schedule.h"
#import "AnotherViewController.h"


@implementation Schedule

@synthesize mySchedule;

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return mySchedule.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //create a cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                                   reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    //fill it with contents
    cell.textLabel.text = [mySchedule objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //return it
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    AnotherViewController *anotherViewController = [[AnotherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
    [anotherViewController release];



}

/*
 // The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *myFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"exercise" ofType:@"plist"];
    mySchedule = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myFile];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}


/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: I used to run across this -- typically my tableView.dataSource and tableView.delegates were not wired up correctly.

I notice that your interface uses UIViewController with protocols rather than UITableViewController. Try that?

Comment: If I do that I get the error message: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "Schedule" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'

Could it be that I am not using the same header file for both declaring the tab bar and using it as a root view controller?

Comment: Re - your reply to my answer below - Yeah, you need to do more than that. Just saying Schedule implements the protocol isn't enough. When you create Schedule and push it onto the Navigation Stack, you'll need to explicitly set the Table View's delegate. Please post the code where you create Schedule so we can take a look.

Comment: Still not enough info. You're creating an instance of Schedule, and putting it into some array, but where does that array go? I really think you need to take a look at the Apple docs in the iPhone Dev Center on how View Controllers work, specifically UINavigationController and UITabBarController.

Answer (score 0):

Need more code/info. It looks like you implemented tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: and pushed another View Controller onto the stack correctly, so it's hard to say. But here's a hit list:

- Are you certain tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is getting called? Did you set a breakpoint? If not, you may have forgotten to set your Schedule class as the delegate either programatically or in Interface Builder.
- Is schedule's navigation controller definitely set? That is, was it pushed onto a Navigation Controller stack?
- Are you sure the nib file for AnotherViewController exists?

Comment: 1.  I have an NSLog statement that tells me the method is being called.    

2.  In "schedule" I have declared it as the <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> in my header.  Do I need to do this in my rootViewController where I am loading my tabs?

3.  The nib does exist.